# How to display only significant decimals in UILabel?

Tags: objective-c, ios, c, ios5

I need to set a label to a number, which may or may not have decimals. I dont want it to be 5.00, just 5 (which may happen when using a standard token). Although, if there are significant decimals, like .56, then it should display 5.56; if it's .5, then it should display 5.56. Other than by just using a bunch of if-statements, how can I only show the decimals needed (i.e. is there a quick fix or do I need to do this manually)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In cocoa the best way to format number values for display is with [NSNumberFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[formatter setMaximumSignificantDigits:2];

NSNumber *significant = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:10.56f];
NSNumber *nonSignificant = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:10.00f];

NSLog(@"sig: %@, non-sig: %@", [formatter stringFromNumber:significant], [formatter stringFromNumber:nonSignificant]);
//sig: 10.56, non-sig: 10
```

Comment: @BenSender Have you even _tried_ to configure a NSNumberFormatter?